# Is it possible to key-bind the pasting of the x-clipboard? How?

Tags: xorg, clipboard, paste, clipboard-manager

I was wondering if it is possible to add a keybind to paste the x-clipboard in Lubuntu. 
(primary selection)

If possible to keybind it, would you still be able to use the middle-click too?
Is there perhaps a clipboard manager that supports this?

Thanks in advance,
Zarnaik

**Edit: Thanks to Kupiakos for providing a solution. I have not tested it in Ubuntu, Lubuntu only.**
This is how I did it. 
First run

> sudo apt-get install xsel xvkbd

to install the necessary packages. Then open the openbox configuration file as so

> gedit ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

replacing gedit by whatever text-editor you use.
Once inside the file look for the `<keyboard>` tag and add the below code.

```
<keybind key="W-v">
  <action name="Execute">
<command>sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -xsendevent -file -'</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

I configured it to work with Super + v, but you can easily adjust that. Save the file and make openbox notice the change by executing

> openbox --reconfigure

That's all there is to it. 
Again thanks to **Kupiakos** for providing the command that I still fail to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run this command to install the necessary X utilities: `sudo apt-get
   install xsel xvkbd`
2. Navigate to the Shortcuts section of the Keyboard Settings in System
   Settings.
3. Create a new custom shortcut. Put whatever you want in the `Name`
   field.
4. In the `Command` field, put this: `sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -xsendevent
   -file -'`.
5. Click `Apply`.
6. Click on the far right of the new row you created (where it says `Disabled`) and set the new keyboard shortcut.
7. Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

I found a cool solution as well. You can use something called xdotool to type C-V for you. Just bind your new paste key using whichever method you like (xbindkeys, openbox rc, etc) to the following script:

```
xdotool keydown Control key V keyup Control
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This can be pretty useful but it bothers me it doesn't work for pasting into a terminal (I had something similar bound to a hotkey)